# React router dom add headers and dashboard for certain routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react router dom Version 5 in my react version 15 application, I want to know how I can display the page header and the dashboard in all the pages except the authentication and the sign up pages.

I tried to do a test on the pathname but I always had a lag when I change pages or when I try to disconnect, I have to refresh the page each time.
Here's my code :

```
          <Router>
            {pathname !=='/' && pathname !== '/sign-in' && pathname !== '/sign-up' && 
              <>
                <Header></Header>
                <Dashboard ></Dashboard> 
              </>  
            }
          <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
                {
                  sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null ?
                  <Redirect  to='/sign-in'/>  :
                  <>
                  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/management" component={Management} />
                  <Redirect  to='/home'/>  :

                </>
                }
                
          </Switch>
          </Router>
```

EDIT :
I'm trying  with render inside route tag ,It's worked fine. But, I would like to optimize my code :

```
          <Router>
          <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
                <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
                {
                  sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null ?
                  <Redirect  to='/sign-in'/>  :
                  <>
                  <Route path="/home" render={() =><> <Header/> 
                  <Dashboard/><Home/></>} />
                  <Route path="/management"  render={() =><> <Header/> 
                  <Dashboard /><Management/></>} />
                  <Redirect  to='/home'/>  :

                </>
                }
                
          </Switch>
          </Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v5 you can render the `Header` and `Dashboard` into a `Route` with an array of paths you want them to be rendered on. Render the `Route` within the `Router` but outside the `Switch` so it can be inclusively matched and rendered.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Route path={["/home", "/management]}>
    <>
      <Header />
      <Dashboard /> 
    </>
  </Route>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
    {sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null
      ? <Redirect  to='/sign-in'/>
      : (
        <>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/management" component={Management} />
          <Redirect  to='/home'/>
        </>
    )}      
    <Route path='/' component={SignIn} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

If the number of routes to allow far outnumbers the routes to want to hide the header and dashboard, then use the `children` render function and access the `location` prop.

```
<Router>
  <Route 
    children={({ location }) => {
      return !["/", "/sign-in", "/sign-up"].includes(location.pathname)
        ? (
          <>
            <Header />
            <Dashboard /> 
          </>
        )
        : null;
    }}
  />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
    {sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null
      ? <Redirect  to='/sign-in'/>
      : (
        <>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/management" component={Management} />
          <Redirect  to='/home'/>
        </>
    )}      
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Or abstract the header and dashboard into a component that uses the `useRouteMatch` hook to test against an array of routes to be excluded on.

```
const HeaderDash = () => {
  const isExcludedMatch = useRouteMatch({
    path: ["/", "/sign-in", "/sign-up"],
    exact: true,
  });
  return isExcludedMatch
    ? null
    : (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Dashboard /> 
      </>
    );
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Route component={HeaderDash} />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
    {sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null
      ? <Redirect  to='/sign-in'/>
      : (
        <>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/management" component={Management} />
          <Redirect  to='/home'/>
        </>
    )}      
  </Switch>
</Router>
```